# How to distinguish between Build and Run in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to set a proxy environment variable during the build of a container. But the proxy environment variable must not be set, when the container runs.

I have used the ENV command in the Dockerfile to set the variable. But this sets the variable during the build and the run of the container. As far as I can see the Dockerfile does not support a unset for ENV commands.

How to specify an environment for the build but not for the run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is the build arg which is not persisted in the image. The  doc section [Set build-time variables (--build-arg](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)) describes exactly what you want:

> You can use ENV instructions in a Dockerfile to define variable
>   values. These values persist in the built image. However, often
>   persistence is not what you want. Users want to specify variables
>   differently depending on which host they build an image on.
>
> A good example is http_proxy or source versions for pulling
>   intermediate files. The ARG instruction lets Dockerfile authors define
>   values that users can set at build-time using the --build-arg flag:

```
FROM alpine

ARG hello
RUN env # This will output hello=world

CMD env # When running the container, there is not env variable "hello"
```

---

```
docker build --build-arg hello=world -t test . # This will output hello=world env variable
docker run test # There is no env variable "hello"
```

As you can see above the `hello` shows as an env variable only on build. It is not persisted in the image so it doesn't show on `docker run`

Comment: Does `ARG` set an environment variable?

Comment: @ceving my previous comment was misleading. There is an env variable is present on when building but not when running the container. Updated answer with an example.

Comment: The Docker documentation is vague. The simple sentence, that ARG also sets an environment variable, would make the Docker documentation much more evident.

Comment: This page explains it well: https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/#arg-and-env-availability

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the variable to empty or null? It will still exist but won't have a value which you can account for during runtime